# What is the best webrtc sfu server for voice call large group?

Tags: webrtc, kurento, janus, licode

I want to create app and website , server can join a room and voice chat (100 users) like Ptt(Push to talk). I find out that webrtc can do it, so I use Peerjs. After that I saw some many problems that can't not work with large group user. I know sfu server can solve my problem. Should I choose one between Jitsy vs Janus vs Kurento vs Licode for Nodejs Server and 1 room over 100+ users voice call. Thanks everybody

Comment: if you need complete freedom in your coding medooze is one of the option https://github.com/medooze

Comment: @BijuKalanjoor Thank you for your support. Have you ever try using Murmur server for your project.  I just found it some days ago. I think it can using for Push to talk server, but need to custom some features of backend, and web, ios, android client.

Comment: not yet. I'm implementing medooze in my app. The main drawback i feel no good samples for conference also lack of well explained documnetation.